# Listing product with the fixed maximum number of products to display

Tags: algorithm, logic

My app has a feature to list the fixed number of products(say 5) in the screen.

```
int max=5;
 //when the next button is clicked
 if(start<=items)
{
start=start+max;
}
//when the previous button is clicked
start=start-max;


for(int i=start;i<=start+max;i++)
{
//list products process
}
```

There can be 3 or 17 or may be 26 products.But the algorithm is designed such that it has to go through the multiple of 5.Which say for 17 product load 20 products,which can crash the application. My question is "Is there a way we can avoid the extra product loading"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the upper-bound here:

```
for(int i=start;i<=start+max;i++)
{
    //list products process
}
```

from `start + max` to `min(start + max , item_count - 1)`, where item count is the total number of items. The -1 is only necessary, if you use a language with 0-based array-indices.